# Check if a GameObject has been assigned in the inspector in Unity3D 2019.3.05f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, isnull

**Question:**

> How to check if a public gameObject of a MonoBehaviour has been assigned in the inspector in
>   Unity3D, as the comparison for null `(object==null)` fails.

**Concrete Example:**

I am about to write a generic method for Unity3D, that can be called on any nullable object. It checks if the object is null and if so it writes a `Debug.LogError(customMessage)`. The Method looks like as follows:

```
 public static bool IsNull<T>([CanBeNull] this T myObject, string message = "")
 {
     if (myObject!= null) return false;
     Debug.LogError("The object is null! " + message);
     return true;
 }
```

The method can be called on any nullable object, anywhere in the code, for example within this simple Monobehaviour:

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject testObject = null;

    public void TestObject()
    {
        var result = testObject.IsNull("Error message");
        Debug.Log(result);
        Debug.Log(testObject);
    }
}
```

For most use cases my method works perfectly and saves a lot of time during encoding/debugging. But my problem now is that if I haven't signed the "testObject" in the editor, my test won't work because the testObject seems to be not null, but it's also not usable because it's not assigned. In this case, the console output is:

> False
>   null

How comes that `(myObject == null)` is false, while the `Debug.Log(testObject)` gives me `null` as long as the corresponding object has not been asigned in the unity inspector.

**Edit/Solution:**
Thanks to the help from derHugo I ended up with this generic code snippet:

```
 public static bool IsNull<T>(this T myObject, string message = "") where T : class
    {
        switch (myObject)
        {
            case UnityEngine.Object obj when !obj:
                Debug.LogError("The object is null! " + message);
                return true;
            case null:
                Debug.LogError("The object is null! " + message);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unity has a custom implementation of equality `==` operator (see [Custom == operator, should we keep it?](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it) which often leads to confusion / unexpected behavior.

Even if an `UnityEngine.Object` has a value *equal to* `null` it is sometimes not `== null`.
`Object` rather still stores some meta data in it e.g. you get a `MissingReferenceException`, not a usual `NullReferenceException` because Unity implemented some custom exceptions that often hold more detail to **why** the value is equal to `null`.

Especially since

```
public GameObject testObject = null;
```

is a `public` field it is automatically **serialized** and thus the `null` value you assigned to it will be overwritten anyway during the serialization.

---

[`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) which `GameObject` derives from has an implicit operator [`bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

> Does the object exist?

Instead of a direct `== null` comparison you should rather check for

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T myObject, string message = "") where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    if(!myObject)
    {
        Debug.LogError("The object is null! " + message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

For a general method working for any reference type you could e.g. use something like

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T myObject, string message = "") where T : class
{
    if (myObject is UnityEngine.Object obj)
    {
        if (!obj)
        {
            Debug.LogError("The object is null! " + message);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (myObject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("The object is null! " + message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty good. Thank You. Is there a way to overload this method in a way that it also applies to all Not Unity Engine objects, that I then can check all other nullables for null in the "classic" way?