# Multiple component references in an if/then logic statements in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

How do you make multiple component references in a single if/then logic statements in Unity? I thought it would look something like this:

```
if(other.GetComponent<Component1>() != null || (GetComponent2>() != null)
     {
     //Run code
     }
```

Such code returns this error:

```
error CS1026: ) expected
```

Comment: Put another ) afte if(other.GetComponent<Component1>() != null || (Component2>() != null)

Comment: Btw you shouldn't compare types inherited from `UnityEngine.Object` to `null` **at all** see e.g. [Check if object is referenced in the Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189192/check-if-a-gameobject-has-been-assigned-in-the-inspector-in-unity3d-2019-3-05f)

Comment: @Sergey That seems to fix it but it gives me two errors that say the type or namespace  Component1 and Component2 cannot be found (error CS0246).

Comment: You have to add "using ....namespace" to your code. You should find for the namespace of each component. If it is the trird party components maybe you have to install them at first.

Comment: They are the names of gameObjects though... it works with just one but I need two.

Comment: @Sergey what would I do then?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a get for the second component and a close )

```
if(other.GetComponent<Component1>() != null || other.GetComponent<Component2>() != null)
{
 //Run code
}
```

With out knowing more, this is a start